# Error using netCDF4 python module

Tags: python, netcdf

I am using netCDF4 and python 3.4.

I run the following line of code in order to start writing a new netCDF file that I will be filling with data later in my code following netcdf4 documentation.  I however keep getting this error...

***File "netCDF4.pyx", line 1466, in netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4.c:19692) RuntimeError: Permission denied***

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
rootgrp = Dataset('test.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
```

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Permission denied" part of the error leads me to believe you don't have permissions to write to the current directory (wherever you are when you run your script).

Check your permissions and/or try giving a full path to put the file in a directory you know you can write to.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

> dataset.close()

or close ide and delete file 'netCDF4.pyx'

maybe a file exist there, so can't write it.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this error arises when I am running python by crontab.

The solution is to add following line at the beginning of crontab file.

```
HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE
```